# How do I execute UserData content in a Windows EC2 instance

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-cloudformation

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get a Cloud Formation template running correctly with auto scaling. I have the following resource:

```
"LaunchConfig" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Properties" : {
    "KeyName" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "EnvironmentToKeyName", { "Ref" : "Environment" }, "KeyName" ] },
    "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionToAMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "AMI" ] },
    "SecurityGroups" : [ "neat_spi" ],
    "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
    "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : {
        "Fn::Join" : ["", [ "<script>", "call c:\\chef\\boot.bat", { "Ref" : "Environment" }, "</script>"]]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't look like this script is running at all when the machine is started. How do I make sure it runs? Or how do I figure out why it isn't running?

I can't find any logging anywhere on how to see if this was run or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the VM boots, you can run remote commands on it with WinRM. Here's an example client:

https://github.com/WinRb/WinRM

Make sure WinRM is enabled in your Windows AMI and that the correct port is open in the security group.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about UserData.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of things to look for...

1. Verify the cfn tools are installed
2. Look in the c:\cfn subdirectory - there's a path called logs floating around there somewhere - review that.
3. Look under program files\amazon\ec2tools - there's a log directory in there.  Check to make sure that it's running the script
4. In the directory above there's a folder called scripts - you should see something that looks like userdata.bat - try running that to confirm it works.

Troubleshooting CloudFormation and Userdata is time consuming - and can be costly - because you get billed for an hour every time you start and stop the instance.  Something that works to great advantage for Amazon.  (Bring on per minute pricing please)

Comment: C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Logs\Ec2ConfigLog.txt was the most useful file I found. It contains a log of your scripts which are installed under C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Scripts as UserScript.bat/ps1

Answer (score 3):

I had a heck of a time getting the scripts to run on my AMI as well. **It worked when I used a standard Amazon AMI**, but it didn't work with my custom build AMIs.

I then found this link [Create a Standard Amazon Machine Image Using Sysprep](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ami-create-standard.html).

To summarize, I

1. I made sure termination protection was turned on (this caused me to lose all my work once)
2. Launched into a new Windows instance
3. I customized the instance by doing things like installing windows features I needed and installing an .MSI that I needed.
4. I turned on Windows Updates and cleared the recycle bin
5. I ran `EC2ConfigService Settings` from **Start** -> **All Programs**
6. I checked "*Enable UserData execution for next service start (automatically enabled at SysPrep) eg. `<script></script> or <powershell></powershell>`*" on the **General** tab.
7. Make sure you set a proper password policy on the **Image** tab. I chose Random.
8. Click **Apply** and then click **Shutdown with SysPrep**
9. When the EC2 instance is finally stopped, you can create an image from the AWS console.

This new AMI was able to run my UserData scripts properly.